# Failed to set (tintColor)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have tried so many things and none of them solved my problem. 
I am getting warning:

> Failed to set (tintColor) user defined inspected property on
>   (UINavigationController): [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key tintColor.

All the changes in tints I do through StoryBoard. My code Is written in Swift. 
The StoryBoard fragment (when this happens) looks like:

ViewController -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> ViewController

The only "User Defined Runtime Attributes" is `tintColor` (in NavigationController), but removing this didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the `Inspector` of the NavigationController, see if there is some unwanted connection.

Comment: UINavigationController doesn't have tintColor property. You can set tintColor property (tint color value) in the view’s hierarchy, not in view controller's hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, no there is no unwanted connections,

@user3441734 Sorry, I meant i set tintColor of the UITabBarItem,

Moreover, I tried to comment everything with tintColor in the StoryBoard (in SourceCode view), This didn't help either.

Comment: the same .... UITabBarItem is NOT inherited from UIView, so there is NO property tintColor in UITabBarItem .....

Comment: if you would like to change the color of your custom image, follow https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006928-CH3-SW14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, my co-worker set up color of each navigation controller separately. Just delete "tintColor" from all navigation controllers. 
Thanks @user3441734. NavigationController also doesn't inherit from UIView.

Comment: OK, use code set tintColor will override the settings on the storyboard.

Comment: @EricXuan You should use StoryBoard if possible and only custom staff in code. If you do everything in code, you will have mess in bigger projects.

Comment: Yes, u r right. I only post the ways to change tintColor.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change one specific NavigationController's tint color, add the code

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = /*your color*/
```

in the viewController's viewDidLoad().

Or you want to change all the NavigationController's tint color, you can add the code

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = /*your color*/
```

in the func application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

Or you can change the App's tint color in the Storyboard file use the global tint color option.

Comment: I changed it in the StoryBoard and this works, but I am getting warning and I don't understand why.

Comment: In which controller or controllers do you set on the tintColor?